# Add column that shows the range of the min to max value in a datafrmae

Tags: python

I have a dataframe

```
Country Pop_1 Pop_2 Pop_3
UK      50    60    65
France  70    80    90
Italy   40    70    80
```

I would like to add another column 'range' that shows the min-max value

```
Country Pop_1 Pop_2 Pop_3 Range
UK      80    60    65    50-65
France  70    90    80    70-90
Italy   40    70    80    40-80
```

How would I create the 'Range' column?  This is an example dataframe, in my actual dataframe I have 200 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a vectorized approach, you should call `min` and `max` on each dataframe:

```py
max_series = df.max(axis=1, numeric_only=True).astype(str)
min_series = df.min(axis=1, numeric_only=True).astype(str)

df["Range"] = min_series.str.cat(max_series, sep="-")

print(df)
  Country  Pop_1  Pop_2  Pop_3  Range
0      UK     50     60     65  50-65
1  France     70     80     90  70-90
2   Italy     40     70     80  40-80
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.apply` to do that:

```
df["Range"] = df.apply(lambda r: f'{r.min()}-{r.max()}', axis=1)
```

Comment: Im looking for an answer where I don't have to specify which columns have max and min so the solution can work for large datasets

Comment: That's actually even easier. Updated